# Joining Multiple MySQL Queries Together

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I just started learning MySQL, I've learned quite a bit from this website when coming up against problems but I've hit a brick wall with this 1. I wanted to create a log for all the debit card payments made in my 3 stores, grouped by date with 1 column per store and then a total column at the end. With the info I found on here I was able to create the queries separately but not sure how to combine them into 1 output.

### Query to find the total for all stores:

```
SELECT DATE(s.sale_time) AS Date, SUM(p.payment_amount) AS Total
FROM pos_sales_payments p
JOIN pos_sales s on p.sale_id = s.sale_id
WHERE p.payment_type = "Debit Card" AND s.sale_time > "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND s.deleted = "0"
GROUP BY date(s.sale_time)
ORDER BY s.sale_time
```

### Query to find the total of store 1:

```
SELECT DATE(s.sale_time) AS Date, SUM(p.payment_amount) AS Total
FROM pos_sales_payments p
JOIN pos_sales s on p.sale_id = s.sale_id
WHERE p.payment_type = "Debit Card" AND s.sale_time > "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND s.deleted = "0" AND s.location_id = "1"
GROUP BY date(s.sale_time)
ORDER BY s.sale_time
```

Comment: Try looking up the usage of `UNION`

Comment: Does your query work if not what's the problem? What's the data like? What's the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(s.sale_time) AS Date, SUM(p.payment_amount) AS Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.location_id = 1 THEN p.payment_amount ELSE 0 END) as Total_1
FROM pos_sales_payments p JOIN
     pos_sales s 
     ON p.sale_id = s.sale_id
WHERE p.payment_type = 'Debit Card' AND
      s.sale_time >= '2018-01-01' AND
      s.deleted = '0'
GROUP BY date(s.sale_time)
ORDER BY s.sale_time;
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much. I was stumped for a second until I realized you must have typed "a" instead of "as" on line 2. You are a legend!